# How to include separate directories into one project?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a folder outside the document root named Base and a folder inside the document root to display HTML pages.

I originally had them separate projects but that's not the ideal situation obviously?

I saw one suggestion to make the directory which holds Base the project root and to exclude everything except the two directories I need. This works but is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Project | Directories | Add Content Root**

This allows you to make any folder as part of the project (will be listed in Project View panel as separate branch).